# Why is the graph size decreasing in 'Column'?

Tags: plotting, column, imagesize

I printed out the graph in two ways.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}]
Column[{ "Plot[Sin[x],{x,-3,3}]", Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}] }]
```

[image]

Comparing the results of the two outputs, the graph size was different. I want to get the same graph size in 'Column'. Why is that? Of course, you can artificially adjust it using 'ImageSize', but I want to get the same size automatically.

[image]

GraphicsCoulmn has a normal graph size, but the above string is not aligned to the left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [ImageSizeMultipliers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html)

Wrap `Column[...]` with `Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &`:

```
Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] &@
 Column[{"Plot[Sin[x],{x,-3,3}]", Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}]}]
```

[image]

***"Why is the graph size decreasing in `Column`?"***

**See** [ImageSizeMultipliers > > Details](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSizeMultipliers.html):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I want.

Comment: Just a small note: `ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1` is equivalent to `ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}`.